# Cakephp 2.6 : Role wise isAuthorized not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have several method in `UsersController`, I am trying to give role wise access. 
if

1. user_types == 1 (user can access all methods)
2. user_types == 2 (user can't access `admin_list` method.
3. user_types == 3 (user can access only `forget_password` method)

In controller I have tried below code

```
public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler','Auth'=>array(

            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'),
            'authError'=>'You can not access this page!!',
            'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                  'username' => 'email', //Default is 'username' in the userModel
                  'password' => 'password'  //Default is 'password' in the userModel
                )
              ),
            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        ));

        public function isAuthorized($user) {
            return true;
        }
```

In before filter I have allowed

```
    $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
```

Now in `UserController` I have tried below code

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['usertype_id']) && $user['usertype_id'] == 1) {
            return true;
    }
    else if(isset($user['usertype_id']) && $user['usertype_id'] == 2)
    {
         $this->Auth->deny('admin_list');
    }else
        $this->Auth->allow('change_password');

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
```

Problem is it's always returning true. If I login with user_type = 3 , I can access all methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth::allow()` and `Auth::deny()` are meant to define which actions are allowed to be accessed by non logged-in users (*authentication*), and are not to be used for *authorization*.

For this purpose, you have to define `isAuthorized()` in your controller, as you have done. However, this method is expected to return `true` (logged in user/group is authorized to access action) or `false` (authorization is denied).

Your `UsersController::isAuthorized()` method should be rewritten as:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

    if (!isset($user['usertype_id'])) {
        return false;
    }

    if($user['usertype_id'] == 2 && $this->action=='admin_list') {
       return false;           
    }

    if($user['usertype_id'] == 3) && $this->action!='forget_password'){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

See the Cookbook for more on [ControllerAuthorize](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize).

Comment: It's working fine now,Is it possible to make this condition by using inArray() ?

Comment: Sure. You can pass an array of actions to `in_array()`.

Comment: If you don't mind may you provide me an example please?

Comment: To be able to provide an example, I would need to know exactly what you expect it to do. Note that `in_array()` is equivalent to a logic `OR`, and your usertype/action matrix can easily become very complex. If you find yourself in this situation, you may want to use the `AclComponent` instead. It really doesn't matter what you put in `isAuthorized()`, as long it returns `true` or `false` as expected.